# Figure out what redis is actually doing in a laravel app?

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I have a project working on a Laravel app in Laravel 8. The applications requires redis to run but doesn't seem to use redis anywhere. I've logged in and clicked through everything in the application checking redis as I go with KEYS *. Nothing shows up in the cache. Could someone help me understand why the application might use redis if it doesn't put anything in the cache? How can I find the functionality in the code?

Might be stupid questions, I'm new to Laravel. Thank you in advance if you reply

Comment: I have no idea about Laravel, but in Redis you can use the [monitor](https://redis.io/commands/monitor/) command which allows you to trace every command sent to Redis. Be careful about using this command inside a production environment.

Comment: Is your cache driver, or whatever other configuration is used, setup to be redis in your .env?

Comment: Yes the .env is showing predis and the configurations are all for redis. Port 6379. CACHE_DRIVER is set to file